# Code reuse in Dojo Toolkit

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, dojo

I am implementing a mobile application using the Dojo Toolkit. The application has several pages and all pages have the same TabBar. At the moment, the TabBar is hardcoded in every page. So if want to make changes, I need to change the TabBar in every page. How can I solve this problem with the Dojo Toolkit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use dojo.declare, create your custom widget extended by TabBar. Then in your initialization code, require that module and in your markup code, set the dojoType to your custom module name. Something similar to this:

```
require([
     "dojox/mobile/TabBar", 
     "dojox/mobile/TabBarButton"
  ], function ( TabBar, Button ) {

   dojo.declare("myTabBar", [ TabBar ], {

       buildRendering: function() {
           this.inherited(arguments); // call parent
           // add a number of children
           this.addChild( new Button( {
                icon1: 'path/to/image',
                icon1: 'path/to/hoverimage',
                label: 'clickme',
                moveTo:"view1"
           }));
       }
   });
});
```

Instead of an UL / LI html markup in your code, simply add:

```
<div dojoType="myTabBar"></div>
```

Running sample : http://jsfiddle.net/8sD6A/

Comment: not tested.. but it should give you an idea of what declaring is about. use dojo.declare to create a module, which you can reuse and easily convert to DOM via the widget framework (consider looking into templating - see http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/templated/

Comment: see the jsfiddle.net example - there was a little syntax error in the code. Icon are ofc not found.